# R aggregate() Syntax Issue - Trying to Count Values

Tags: r

I have a data set shaped like the following:

```
Buyer | Broker | Brand
```

I am trying to use aggregate to count the number of Buyers by Broker and Brand to quantify market share. It should look like this:

```
Broker | Brand | Buyer_Count

Acme | Nike | 50

Acme | Reebok | 20

Acme | Converse | 30

Megacorp | Nike | 80

Megacorp | Reebok | 120

...
```

I am using:

```
Agg <- aggregate(Buyer ~ Broker + Brand, data = mydata, fun=count)
```

and it says

> "Error in UseMethod("groups") : 
>     no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "character" "

I am pretty sure the issue is `"fun = count"` not being the correct function but am not sure what the correct function would be here.

I tried `match.fun(count)` but did not get one that works there either. I also tried google and didn't find anything.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe `FUN=length`?

Comment: That appears to be working. Can you please explain why you knew to try that?

Comment: It works because `length` returns the number of elements of your object, in this case your object is `Buyer` grouped by `Broker+Brand`, then `length` "counts" how many `Buyers` there are by `Broker+Brand`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how it works. I appreciate the additional detail.